# R: Display a cell value of a column based upon the row value in for each loop

Tags: r

I have the following  data frame

```
glimpse(Sample)
Observations: 4
Variables: 5
$ Product     <chr> "A", "B", "C", "D"
$ Revenues    <dbl> 50, 25, 15, 10
$ Quantity    <dbl> 40, 30, 20, 10
$ RevenueCum  <dbl> 50, 75, 90, 100
$ QuantityCum <dbl> 40, 70, 90, 100
```

I want to use a for loop to display each row for columns one by one.However, my code is printing all the values for the columns in every iteration.

```
length=nrow(Sample)
for (i in 1:length)
{print(i)
  Sample %>%select(Revenues, Quantity) %>%  print(Revenues[i-1]," ",Revenues[i]," ",Quantity[i-1]," ",Quantity[i])
 print(i)

}
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
[1] 1
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Revenues Quantity
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       50       40
2       25       30
3       15       20
4       10       10
[1] 1
[1] 2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Revenues Quantity
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       50       40
2       25       30
3       15       20
4       10       10
[1] 2
[1] 3
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Revenues Quantity
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       50       40
2       25       30
3       15       20
4       10       10
[1] 3
[1] 4
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Revenues Quantity
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       50       40
2       25       30
3       15       20
4       10       10
[1] 4
>
```

EDIT:
What I plan to do, is to it print a ggplot so that I can use these required values of Revenue and Quantity to add a rectangle at each iteration of the for loop. At each iteration, these values will be used as the four co-ordinates of the rectangle.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that R doesn't throw an error complaining that `object Revenues not found`. I'm pretty sure that once you move into `print`, you no longer get to use `tidyverse`'s evaluation of objects, so `Revenues` and `Quantiy` are no longer objects. This is part of the problem with everyone trying to turn everything into a chain of pipes. In this instance, the pipe doesn't do anything for you. You can achieve your goal by simply using `print(samples$Revenues[i-1], " ", samples$Revenues[i], " ", samples$Quantities[i-1], samples$Quantities[i])`.

Comment: Also probably worth pointing out that starting your loop at `i=1` will cause an error because R doesn't allow 0-index of vectors, so in the first loop you'll try taking `Revenues[1-1]`, which will be `Revenues[0]`, which will error.

Comment: Its more helpful to "show what you really want" then to "show what undesired result you're getting".

Comment: @brittenb `Sample$Revenues[0]` will not error, it is just empty `integer(0)`

Comment: @Nicolas2 Hmm.. didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @bittenb I tried using it as well, but I am getting the Error in print.default(Sample$Revenues[i - 1], " ", Sample$Revenues[i],  : 
  invalid 'digits' argument

Comment: Perhaps you just need something as `print(paste0(Sample$Revenues[i-1]," ",Sample$Revenues[i]," ",Sample$Quantity[i-1]," ",Sample$Quantity[i]))

Comment: @Nicolas2 Thanks I am able to get the data using paste(0), but originally I planned to use these variables to plot a rectangle at each iteration. I can't get the value of each variable separately for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be heading in this direction.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
sample <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  Product = c(LETTERS[1:4]),
  Revenues = c(50, 25, 15, 10),
  Quantity = c(40, 30, 20, 10)
) %>%
  mutate(RevenueCum = cumsum(Revenues),
         QuantityCum = cumsum(Quantity))


# Add prior totals and set as zero where not available
sample_shapes <- sample %>%
  mutate(RevenueCum_prior = lag(RevenueCum, default = 0),
         QuantityCum_prior = lag(QuantityCum, default = 0))

# Plot
ggplot(sample_shapes, aes(xmin = QuantityCum_prior, ymin = RevenueCum_prior, 
                          xmax = QuantityCum, ymax = RevenueCum, fill = Product)) +
  geom_rect() +
  labs(x = "Cumulative Quantity",
       y = "Cumulative Revenue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was exactly what I was looking for!